# sorting of words in lexicographic order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given n words, is it possible to sort them in lexicographic order with o(n) time complexity?? Well i found a method like creating a trie data structure and an inorder traversal of the trie would result in time complexity close to O(kn) where k is the arbitrary string length, but the problem here being space complexity. constructing BST and inorder traversal is also a good option but time complexit is O(nlogn) . So could anyone suggest me whoch would be better BST or trie given the constraints of both. Any other algorithm or suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: You *might* hit amortized `O(n)` if you're willing to trade-off for extra space, but there is no method of sorting unsorted data that is going to give you `O(n)` worst (or even average!) case behavior.

Comment: @Gian: False.  You are not restricted to comparison-based sorting here.

Comment: @tmyklebu No non-comparison-based sorting algorithm is purely O(n), there's always an additional variable that comes into play. However, if your data conforms, you could upper-bound this variable with a constant and thus end up with O(n).

Comment: @tmyklebu, which non-comparison sort gives `O(n)` worst or average case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to sort the words in `O(nL)` time with a [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) or [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).  Here `L` is word length.  It's impossible to do better, since you must look at all the keys at least once.

Your [triesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Sorting) idea is an old one.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to do better because you need to look at each *letter* at least once.  Notice, however, that you're assuming a fixed alphabet.

Comment: @tmyklebu Length of word includes alphabetic encoding.  Think length of word in bits.